# Python interaction with the output using a script

Tags: python

I have a python script "Script1.py" that I do not change the inside of. I want to interact with its output using another script(.py or .bat). The script "Script1.py" gives a lot of options with `print()`, and I should choose each time.

So, is there a way to read his output and send him the right options that I need with another script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 2):

Put the code inside a function and call it with an import. Also, you can use `if __name__ == '__main__'` to execute the module as an script.

```
def function_generic_name(arg1,arg2):
    **code**
    return something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    function_generic_name(arg1,arg2)
```